# flutter desktop app crash when the right control key is pressed

Tags: flutter, desktop, keyboard-events

My flutter desktop app got crashed after I pressed right contro and it was coincidence

```
    ======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following assertion was thrown during a platform message callback:
A KeyUpEvent is dispatched, but the state shows that the physical key is not pressed. If this occurs in real application, please report this bug to Flutter. If this occurs in unit tests, please ensure that simulated events follow Flutter's event model as documented in `HardwareKeyboard`. This was the event: KeyUpEvent#57fd1(physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#700e4(usbHidUsage: "0x000700e4", debugName: "Control Right"), logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#00101(keyId: "0x200000101", keyLabel: "Control Right", debugName: "Control Right"), character: null, timeStamp: 122:53:43.248297, synthesized)
'package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart':
Failed assertion: line 441 pos 16: '_pressedKeys.containsKey(event.physicalKey)'
```

after that I wrapped my entire app with RawKeyboardListener and I tried almost all the keyboard keys and the right control is the only key that lead the crash of the app,
the left control did not lead to app crash when it was pressed

Comment: Similar exceptions here.. does it happen even in release mode?